# How does wok relative time in different time zones?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I am confused about using datetimes in databases and applications for international users. My application is developed asp.net web api and c# programming language.

I am using a column in database (postgresql) named `created_at` that type is without timezone.

When New York Time `2020-11-02 23:50:00`, London Time is  `2020-11-03 04:50:00`. So day and hour is different.

And I want to show dates in relative time like `Now, 1 Hours ago, 10 minutes ago...`

If Someone adds a record in database at `2020-11-03 04:50:00` in London, someone shows the record as relative time `5 hours after`. This looks a little strange.

Is this a true logic? How does it workin real applications?

Comment: `DateTime.UtcNow` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.utcnow

Comment: _"How does it workin real applications?"_ You'd normalize to _one_ specific timezone internally. Most dev teams would probably chose UTC, since it is designed exactly for this. Convertion to local times only come into play at the last step: the UI.

Comment: ^^ Be aware that there are still a lot of pitfalls, but most are well documented and there are plenty of "best practices" articels to be found via the search engine of your choice.

Comment: What type will be database column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store your datetime as UTC and convert it to the users time zone correspondingly.
Or you could store your values in postgreSQL via its designated time types. 
(see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html)

Comment: So briefly, how will he see in New York as relative if I use UTC?

Comment: @barteloma You need send the UTC timestamp to your frontend/UI (browser if a recall). There determine the timezone of the user (e.g. with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-offset-in-javascript)) and calculate the local time in UI from it. Then substract that value from the "localtime now" value also gathered in the UI.